# Not noticing that you have a sequence

Tags: sequence

If a player does not realize he made a sequence for a complete round of plays, can the next player play a one-eyed jack and remove one of the chips in that sequence, thereby undoing the Sequence?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot remove a sequence.

[Rules:](https://www.nordicgames.is/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Sequence_Rules_EN.pdf)

> You cannot remove a marker chip that is already part of a completed SEQUENCE. Once a SEQUENCE is achieved by a player or a team, it cannot be broken.

Note that it doesn’t mention anything about noticing or declaring that you made a sequence. There is no requirement to announce or declare that you have made a sequence.